# Editing Video once Sound Starts

Tags: audio, video, video-editing

I have a large batch of videos that has this loading screen from the program I used to make them and I was wondering if there was a program that would cut that part out and create a new file when the sound of the video starts playing.

I know I can do it manually but it would take forever as I have over 50 videos that I need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:

[FFMPEG used to trim a video](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg)

I think it answers your question (unless the question also requires some sort of automated way to detect the start of sound activity).